# Cell Styles switch to date format when file is moved from local Windows computer to Amazon Workspaces hosted dekstop

Tags: excel, amazon-web-services

My company recently migrated all users to hosted desktops through Amazon Workspaces. As part of the migration, we mapped to a network drive on a shared file server hosted by Amazon, and transferred each user's files to their own location in their workspace. For about 20% of users, Excel files moved from their local computers are opening in their workspace with all blank cells formatted to Date (instead of General) and it is changing the formatting on anything added to these workbooks. When they open the file on their local computer, the formatting issue is gone.

Comment: Isn't this a question for Amazon Workspaces tech support?

Comment: I thought that until I spoke with them for hours. They told me its an excel setting in the code